# RVM : cannot find installed ruby

Tags: ruby, rvm

When i cd into a project with .ruby-version file i get an error about corresponding ruby version not installed.

```
$ cd my-app/
ruby-2.0.0p451 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.0.0p451'
```

**I installed it with RVM and still have the error.**

---

More info :

I have rvm installed and i got it working without problem for some time. I recently needed ruby-2.0.0p451 for a project, after installing i was able to use it :

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]
```

But when i add a .ruby-version file it seems RVM cannot find ruby

Here is a copy of my [.bashrc](https://gist.github.com/vdaubry/9828161) and [bash_profile](https://gist.github.com/vdaubry/9828181)

Comment: have you tried `rvm reload`, then `rvm list`?

Comment: put the line: `[[ -s "/Users/vincentdaubry/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/Users/vincentdaubry/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*`  at the end of **bash_profile**. then reopen console